# Error using ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN syntax

Tags: sql-server, variables

I'm making a way for our developers to easily update our database.  The way we're doing this is by creating dynamic queries where they define the variables at the top and the query uses the variables for everything else.  I've used many recommendations off Stackoverflow, but can't get this to work.

```
USE MyDatabase
DECLARE @TABLE VARCHAR(200) = 'MyTable'
DECLARE @COLUMN VARCHAR(200) = 'MyColumn'
DECLARE @DATATYPE VARCHAR(200) = 'VARCHAR(200)'

IF COL_LENGTH(@TABLE, @COLUMN) IS NULL
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL as NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @TABLE + ' ADD COLUMN ' 
      + @COLUMN +' '+ @DATATYPE
    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
END
```

I get the error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'COLUMN'.

Comment: Looking at the [`ALTER TABLE` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx), you can't specify the `COLUMN` keyword there. You have to specify it when dropping a column, but it is not legal syntax when adding. It's one of those SQL Server inconsistencies that nobody can really justify but is also unlikely to ever get fixed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the error message indicates that is the wrong syntax. [Somewhat confusingly](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/124626/add-column-keyword-to-the-add-column-syntax-as-alternate) the `COLUMN` keyword is not permitted when adding a column.

Also `VARCHAR(200)` should really be `SYSNAME` to cope with all possible valid names (currently equivalent to `nvarchar(128)`) and use `QUOTENAME` to correctly escape any object names containing `]`

More about this is in [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL: Dealing with Dynamic Table and Column Names](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#objectnames)

Comment: Oh gosh...  Fail.  I should have read more closely.  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp

Comment: @Chris well you [shouldn't have started at w3schools](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/discouraging-w3schools-as-a-resource), anyway. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I highly suggest against doing this due to exposure to SQL injection. However, if you must, remove the word COLUMN from your script and it should work.

```
USE MyDatabase
DECLARE @TABLE VARCHAR(200) = 'MyTable'
DECLARE @COLUMN VARCHAR(200) = 'MyColumn'
DECLARE @DATATYPE VARCHAR(200) = 'VARCHAR(200)'

IF COL_LENGTH(@TABLE, @COLUMN) IS NULL
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL as NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @TABLE + ' ADD ' + @COLUMN     +' '+ @DATATYPE
    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
END
```

Comment: Note that the code is for internal use by developers - they're not taking random form input from strangers.